# Windows SID and ObjectGUID for user NOT in a domain

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify a user with something that won't change. Do user accounts not in a domain have an ObjectGUID that I can access?

When the user is in a domain, I know I can do the following to get the ObjectGUID

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
SecurityIdentifier sid = user.User;

using (DirectoryEntry userDe = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<SID=" + sid.Value + ">"))
{
    Guid objectGuid = new Guid(userDe.NativeGuid);
}
```

However does the concept of ObjectGUID exists for none domain user?

Comment: Every Windows account has a SID. No matter if it's in domain or not.

Comment: That's not my question - my question is does every Windows account have an ObjectGUID or is that only found for domain users?

Comment: Well, your initial question is about "a way to to uniquely identify a user". And SID is that way.

Comment: From my understanding a SID may change if the user is moved domain within an Enterprise - but the ObjectGUID is constant. Hence the original question of does an ObjectGUID exist for a non domain user...

Comment: Then please change your question accordingly. Your title is explicitely about a non-domain user.